# D flip flop how to check my delay between the input and output when clock is rising edge?

Tags: vhdl, timing

I wrote a code for a D-flipflop with 8 inputs and 8 outputs. 
I want to check how long it takes to transfer the data of the inputs when clock is rising till it gets to the output `Q`.

This is my code:

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;


entity Input_ADC is 
   port(
      Q7,Q6,Q5,Q4,Q3,Q2,Q1,Q0: out std_logic;    
      Clk :in std_logic;   
         reset :in  std_logic;-- Reset input
      D7,D6,D5,D4,D3,D2,D1,D0 :in  std_logic    
   );
end Input_ADC;
architecture Behavioral_of_rising_edge_Dflipflops of Input_ADC is  
begin  

  D0_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D0
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q0<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q0<= D0; 
            end if;       
 end process D0_process;  

    D1_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D1
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q1<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q1<= D1; 
            end if;       
 end process D1_process;  

   D2_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D2
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q2<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q2<= D2; 
            end if;       
 end process D2_process;  

   D3_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D3
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q3<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q3<= D3; 
            end if;       
 end process D3_process;  

    D4_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D4
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q4<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q4<= D4; 
            end if;       
 end process D4_process;  

   D5_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D5
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q5<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q5<= D5; 
            end if;       
 end process D5_process;  

    D6_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D6
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q6<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q6<= D6; 
            end if;       
 end process D6_process;  

    D7_process:process(Clk,reset)  --------flip flop D7
 begin 
            if(reset='0') then 
                    Q7<= '0';
            elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                    Q7<= D7; 
            end if;       
 end process D7_process;  
end Behavioral_of_rising_edge_Dflipflops;
```

As I found, I need to use timing  analyzer to find out the delay. For this I need to write an SDC file. Is there another way to find out the delay? If not, could some one show me an example how to do it? I did not find a good example for signal delays.

Comment: This is not a VHDL problem. You are measuring the delay in the hardware, not your code. Hence you need the SDC file to explain to the tool what the timing requirements are, and it will analyse what has happened in reality.

Comment: Implement your code (synthesis, mapping, optimization, placing, routing) and do a static timing analysis (STA).